# Find equation of circle(s) tangent to $2x − y − 5 = 0$ and $2x + y − 7 = 0$ passing through $(10, −3)$.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Find equation of circle(s) tangent to $2x − y − 5 = 0$ and
$2x + y − 7 = 0$ passing through $(10, −3)$.

I tried using Angle bisector but couldn't get the solution

Comment: Are you allowed to use derivatives?

Comment: Solve it without derivatives

Comment: Maybe we could use angle bisector and Distance of a point from a line

Comment: @Doug I tried doing that but we dont get the correct value

Comment: It's not easy to try Angle bisector. See [PLL: Apollonius' Problem with Two Lines and a Point](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PLL.shtml) for detail.

Comment: So what can be the solution,Can you give a detailed solution for this questions

Comment: Hint: a circle is tangent to a line when there is only one root pair $(x,y)$. In detail, get a quadratic equation by eliminating *x* or *y*, the [Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) should be 0.

Comment: but how can I proceed

Comment: Anyone Please help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find equation of circle(s) tangent to 2x−y−5=0 and 2x+y−7=0 passing through (10,−3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528049/find-equation-of-circles-tangent-to-2x%e2%88%92y%e2%88%925-0-and-2xy%e2%88%927-0-passing-through-10)

Comment: That solution didnt help anyone else could help me here

Comment: I think someone did upload the answer but has now deleted it?

Comment: Any new solution,anyone can please help

Comment: This is an interesting question, thanks for posting it. Could you please add some context, for example mentioning where did you see this question, why do you urgently need a solution (is it an assignment you sould hand in soon?), is it a fun project you wish to get into "shapes" or the like. Providing context will make people on this website feel the mathamtical pain with you and help you out. By the way, why can't one use "derivatives"?

Comment: I got this question from my friend

Comment: Anyone can give me a alternate solution would be good

Answer (score 4):

Note that bisectors will be parallel to axis $y$ and axis $x$ as slopes of tangent lines are opposite. The tangents intersect at $2x-5=-2x+7 \implies x=3, y=1$. Looking at the point $(10,-3)$ we can deduct that the center of the circle is on the line $y=1$ (this bisector goes thru the East quadrant where the point is located).
 The distance from the center $(x_c,1)$ to point $(10,-3)$ is $r=\sqrt{(x_c-10)^2+(1+3)^2}=\sqrt{(x_c-10)^2+16}$.

The distance from the center to one of the lines: $r=\frac{|2x_c-1-5|}{\sqrt{4+1}}$.

$$\frac{|2x_c-6|}{\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{(x_c-10)^2+16}$$

Squaring both sides: $(2x_c-6)^2=5(x_c-10)^2+80$ which will produce $x_c=8$ or $x_c=68$. Which leads to two equations:
$$(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2=(8-10)^2+16=20$$ and
$$(x-68)^2+(y-1)^2=(68-10)^2+16=3380$$
[image]

Comment: Which one is correct

Comment: @MathsGeek: both are correct

Comment: How did you get y=1

Comment: $(3,1)$ is the intersection of the two lines, bisectors are $x=3, y=1$

Comment: So shouldnt the centre be 3 then?

Comment: no, because point $(10,3)$ lies in a different quadrant, bisector $x=3$ divides the  other two quadrants/angles

Comment: How did you get (2xc−6)2=5(xc−10)2+80

Comment: @MathsGeek: I updated my answer, hopefully it will be clear to you now

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible that there would be more such circles or there only can be two

Comment: @MathsGeek: only two are possible

Answer (score 3):

This is more geometric, by finding the locus of the center of the desired circle:

[image]

Let $C(O)$ be the desired circle, and $\ell_1: 2x - y - 5 = 0$, $\ell_2: 2x + y - 7 = 0$, and $A = (10, -3)$. Then:

- $C$ is tangent to $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$, so $O$ lies on the bisectors of the angles between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$. (The equations of these two bisectors can be achieved from $\color{purple}{\dfrac{|2x - y - 5|}{\sqrt{5}} = \dfrac{|2x + y - 7|}{\sqrt{5}} \implies x = 3\ \text{or}\ y = 1}$.)
- The distance between $O$ and $\ell_1$ equals the distance between $O$ and $A$. So $O$ lies on a parabola with focus $A$ and directrix $\ell_1$. (Its equation is $\color{blue}{\sqrt{(x - 10)^2 + (y + 3)^2} = \dfrac{|2x - y - 5|}{\sqrt{5}} \implies x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2 - 80x + 20y + 520 = 0}$.)
- The distance between $O$ and $\ell_2$ equals the distance between $O$ and $A$. So $O$ lies on a parabola with focus $A$ and directrix $\ell_2$. (Its equation is $\color{red}{\sqrt{(x - 10)^2 + (y + 3)^2} = \dfrac{|2x + y - 7|}{\sqrt{5}} \implies x^2 - 4xy + 4y^2 - 72x + 44y + 496 = 0}$.)

The parabolas don't intersect the line $x = 3$. So by putting $y = 1$ in the equation of one of the parabolas, we get $x^2 - 76x + 544 = (x - 8)(x - 68) = 0$. So $O = (8, 1)$ or $O = (68, 1)$.

Comment: It would be interesting to see equations for these curves

Comment: @Vasili I did it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The centers of the circles are equidistant from both lines, so if $(C_1, C_2)$ is a center then

$\dfrac{ |2 C_1 - C_2 - 5 |}{\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2}} = \dfrac{ | 2C_1 + C_2 - 7 |}{\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2}}$

which simplifies to

$ |2 C_1 - C_2 - 5 |= | 2C_1 + C_2 - 7 | $

Squaring both sides

$ 4C_1^2 + C_2^2 + 25 - 4 C_1 C_2 - 20 C_1 + 10 C_2 = 4 C_1 + C_2^2 + 49 + 4 C_1 C_2 - 28 C_1 - 14 C_2 $

And this simplifies to

$ 8 C_1 C_2 - 8 C_1 - 24 C_2 + 24 = 0 $

And further to

$ C_1 C_2 - C_1 - 3 C_2 + 3 = 0 \hspace{30pt} (1)$

The second condition we have comes from the equation of the circle

$ (x - C_1)^2 + (y - C_2)^2 = r^2 =  \left( \dfrac{ |2 C_1 - C_2 - 5 |}{\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2}} \right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{5} \left( 4C_1^2 + C_2^2 + 25 - 4 C_1 C_2 - 20 C_1 + 10 C_2 \right) $

The point $(10,-3)$ is on the circle, so

$ 5 \left( (10 - C_1)^2 + (-3 - C_2)^2 \right) = 4C_1^2 + C_2^2 + 25 - 4 C_1 C_2 - 20 C_1 + 10 C_2 $

Simplifying the left hand side, we end up with

$ C_1^2 + 4 C_1 C_2 + 4 C_2^2 -80 C1 + 20 C_2 + 520 = 0 \hspace{30pt} (2) $

Solving $(1) \ \&  \ (2)$ we obtain only **TWO** solutions

- Circle $1$:  Center $ (8, 1)$ , Radius $= \sqrt{20} $
- Circle $2$:  Center $(68, 1)$ , Radius $ =\sqrt{3380} $

Comment: Thanks @Erin is high class

Comment: Note that for solving $|2C_1 - C_2 - 5| = |2C_1 + C_2 - 7|$, we can easily write $2C_1 - C_2 - 5 = \pm(2C_1 + C_2 - 7)$ and there's no need to squaring both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume a circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ is tangent to $2x−y−5=0$, then by eliminating *y* we can get a quadratic equation about *x*:$$(x-a)^2+(2x-b-5)^2=r^2$$

*x* should have only one root so the discriminant should be zero. That is: $$-16a^2+16ab+80a-4b^2-40b+20r^2-100=0\quad\text{(1)}$$

Analogously, when the circle is tangent to $2x+y−7=0$, we get: $$16a^2-16ab+112a-4b^2+56b+20r^2-196=0\quad\text{(2)}$$

When the circle passes through $(10,-3)$, we get: $$(10-a)^2+(-3-b)^2=r^2\quad\text{(3)}$$

The real solutions of *a*, *b* and *r* for Eq (1), (2) and (3) are: $$\begin{cases}a=8\\b=1\\r=\pm2\sqrt{5}\end{cases}$$ and $$\begin{cases}a=68\\b=1\\r=\pm26\sqrt{5}\end{cases}$$

So their are two circles fit the condition: $$(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2=20$$ and $$(x-68)^2+(y-1)^2=3380$$

Comment: How did you eliminate y

Comment: Substitute *y* with $y=2x-5$ in $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.

Comment: How did you get equation no. 1 and 2

Comment: expand $(−)^2+(2−−5)^2=^2$ then get the coeffs of $x^2$ (A), *x* (B) and constant term (C), then $\Delta=B^2-4AC=0$